# How to index views with left outer join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, outer-join

I have created a view which is using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in SQL Server.

I am unable to index the views because you cannot put an `Index` on a view with an `OUTER JOIN`.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an article describing the use of `ISNULL(table_id, 0)` to create an INNER JOIN with the affect of an outer join.  It may be of use to you.

The example in this article is good, should be fairly self-explanatory.

[indexedViewsWithOuterJoins](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexing/indexedviewswithouterjoins/1884/)

Comment: well i tried it already but still indexing is not possible as outer joins are not allowed in indexed views....

Comment: Sorry @Ankit, missed that point in my reading.  I've updated my answer for you with a work around that has been used.

Comment: That's a pretty ugly workaround - it requires you to populate your tables with "null" rows.

Comment: @ Adam well had a look seems to be heavy task..m pulling out data from 10-11 tables and compiling it one view using left outer join...

Comment: Thanks @danihp That was my initial answer too. I have edited the question to try to help the next person who reads it :)

Comment: @Adam well i guess need to restructure my tables as it seems a problem achieving inner join performance advantage using outer join..